# How to read sms when flutter app is closed

Tags: flutter

We are building an app in flutter where we have a requirement to read user sms. We are able to successfully read a message using https://pub.dev/packages/telephony plugin when app is open.  This plugin also provided background message handle which we implemented but still we are not able to read message when app is closed. Is there other way to achieve it.

```
telephony.listenIncomingSms(
        onNewMessage: (SmsMessage message) {
            // Handle message
        },
        onBackgroundMessage: backgroundMessageHandler
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

telephony  not working if app closed  use method channel connect kotlin  create BroadcastReceiver   create service  and   registerReceiver

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` above at onBackgroundMessage

```
    @pragma('vm:entry-point')
onBackgroundMessage(SmsMessage message) async {
```

And in telephony.dart file of package

```
    @pragma('vm:entry-point')
void _flutterSmsSetupBackgroundChannel(
    {MethodChannel backgroundChannel =
        const MethodChannel(_BACKGROUND_CHANNEL)}) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```